# Recoding multiple variables on different scales using across()

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have the following data:

```
data <- data.frame("ID" = c(1:5),
               "Var1" = c(1,0,1,0,0),
               "Var2" = c(99,2,1,3,2))
```

Each variable beginning with "Var" has a different numeric scale. I want to recode these numeric values into text. To do this I can use something like:

```
Var1_recode <- c("1 = 'yes'; 0 = 'no'")
Var2_recode <- c("99 = 'unknown'; 1 = 'weak'; 2 = 'moderate'; 3 = 'strong'")

data_recoded <- data %>%
  mutate(Var1 = car::recode(Var1, Var1_recode),
         Var2 = car::recode(Var2, Var2_recode))
```

However, in a large dataset with lots of columns to be recoded, specifying each recoded variable in `mutate` would lead to lots of repetition. My question: is there a way to use `across` to recode all of my "Var" variables with the relevant recode variables? The output for this example would look like this:

```
  ID Var1     Var2
1  1  yes  unknown
2  2   no moderate
3  3  yes     weak
4  4   no   strong
5  5   no moderate
```

I've tried searching for a solution like the following, but I can't work out a way of specifying the relevant recode vector for each column in my data:

```
data_recoded <- data %>%
  mutate(across(.cols = starts_with("Var"), ~ car::recode(.x, relevant_recode_vector_here)))
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option could be:

```
data %>%
 mutate(across(Var1:Var2, ~ car::recode(., get(paste0(cur_column(), "_recode")))))

  ID Var1     Var2
1  1  yes  unknown
2  2   no moderate
3  3  yes     weak
4  4   no   strong
5  5   no moderate
```

Comment: Exactly the kind of thing I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Include the recode rules in a list and apply it using `Map` :

```
recode_rules <- list(c("1 = 'yes'; 0 = 'no'"), 
     c("99 = 'unknown'; 1 = 'weak'; 2 = 'moderate'; 3 = 'strong'"))

data[-1] <- Map(car::recode, data[-1], recode_rules)
data

#  ID Var1     Var2
#1  1  yes  unknown
#2  2   no moderate
#3  3  yes     weak
#4  4   no   strong
#5  5   no moderate
```